# Noob issue with Latex compilation with makefile

Tags: windows, makefile, latex

I'm totally clueless with Unix-type command line compilation, and now I'm saddled with a document written in LaTEX to compile using a provided makefile.

Bad enough situation, but it gets worse: I work under Windows, have installed all the latex components called by the documentation, including Pygmentize, I even installed Make for Windows, but still can't get it to work.

First of all, what is the correct syntax when calling "Make" to have it use the makefile: just "make", or "make", followed by the intended target pdf file name?

I tried both, the first resulted in:

```
No rule to make target "command" needed by "pdf". Stop.
```

The second got me:

```
No rule to make target "User_manual.pdf". Stop.
```

I searched around, but all results either had nothing to do with my problem, or presupposed much more knowledge about the whole process than I have (in other words, I didn't understand the answer).

So could someone tell me what I did wrong?

Here is the content of the makefile, if it's any use:

```
CURRFILE=User_manual
TEXFILES := $(wildcard *.tex) $(wildcard */*.tex) $(wildcard */*/*.tex)
KBFEXAMPLES := $(wildcard KBF/*.kbf)
PYGEXAMPLES := $(wildcard KBF/*.pyg)
KBFCEXAMPLES := $(patsubst %.kbf,%.pyg,$(KBFEXAMPLES))
CHAPTERNUM := 1 2 3 4 5
PDFLATEX := $(shell command -v pdflatex 2>&1)
BIBTEX := $(shell command -v bibtex 2>&1)
MKINDEX := $(shell command -v makeindex 2>&1)
PDFOPTION=-shell-escape
DICOFILES := $(wildcard *.cfg)
# implement automatic PATH check
PYGMZE_PATH := $(shell command -v pygmentize 2>&1)
# $(shell command -v pygmentize >/dev/null 2>&1 || { @echo >&2 "Missing pygmentize in PATH."; })

all : pdf flat dico

pdf: $(PYGMZE_PATH)
ifeq ($(strip $(PYGMZE_PATH)),)
    ${info PYGMZE_PATH = $(PYGMZE_PATH)}
    $(error ERROR missing pygmentize in PATH)
endif
ifeq ($(strip $(PDFLATEX)),)
    ${info PDFLATEX = $(PDFLATEX)}
    $(error ERROR missing pdflatex in PATH)
endif
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFOPTION) $(CURRFILE).tex
    $(MKINDEX) $(CURRFILE).nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $(CURRFILE).nls -t $(CURRFILE).nlg
    $(BIBTEX) $(CURRFILE)
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFOPTION) $(CURRFILE).tex
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFOPTION) $(CURRFILE).tex

fast: $(KBFEXAMPLES)
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFOPTION) $(CURRFILE).tex

flat:
    #cleartool ls Flat.tex | grep -q CHECKEDOUT || cleartool co -q -nc Flat.tex
    latexpand $(CURRFILE).tex > Flat.tex

dico: apollo_input_dictionary.cfg

apollo_input_dictionary.cfg: Flat.tex
    echo "Generating dictionary"
    ./dictionarygen.sh

updatepyg: $(KBFEXAMPLES)

KBF/%.pyg: KBF/%.kbf
    rm $@


Tex/%.tex: updatepyg FORCE
    sed -n '1,/begin{document}/ p' $(CURRFILE).tex > _region.tex
    cat $@ >> _region.tex
    echo "\end{document}" >> _region.tex
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFOPTION) _region.tex
    $(PDFLATEX) $(PDFOPTION) _region.tex

clean: $(PYGEXAMPLES)
    @for f in $(PYGEXAMPLES); do mv $$f $$f.old; done
    rm -f $(TEXFILES:.tex=.aux)
    rm -f $(CURRFILE).log $(CURRFILE).dvi $(CURRFILE).bbl $(CURRFILE).blg $(CURRFILE).toc $(CURRFILE).lof $(CURRFILE).lot $(CURRFILE).ind $(CURRFILE).out $(CURRFILE).nls $(CURRFILE).nlo $(CURRFILE).nlg $(CURRFILE).kbf $(CURRFILE).dhdf $(CURRFILE).hdf

distclean: clean
    rm -f $(CURRFILE).pdf
    rm -f Flat.tex inputkeyword apollo_input_dictionary.cfg outputkeyword apollo_output_dictionary.cfg

FORCE :

stop:
    $(error ERROR make failed)
```

I have to use the makefile as is, as it is what the customer expects, I just have to know how to make it work in Windows...

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: This makefile is written for POSIX system such as GNU/Linux.  You simply won't be able to run it on Windows at all because it's relying on a lot of POSIX shell features (for example, `command` is a shell built-in that shows the path to the program in question).  Sorry, but there's no straightforward way to make this work on Windows.  You'll either have to rewrite it for Windows, or hope that installing WSL might help (I have no idea), or else run a GNU/Linux virtual machine / Docker image on your Windows system and run it there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was afraid it would come to that, but it looks like I have no choice...

Comment: Indeed, it worked on the first try, though I still have issue with Pygmentize and minted, but that's another story...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in the comments, the problem was with the syntax used in the makefile, which was calling upon Unix-specific commands, so it couldn't work on a pure Windows system. Transposing the package on Linux did the trick.